# Visual Studio 2010 vs. MSBuild Post-Build Events

Tags: msbuild, post-build-event

I have a solution with a number of projects.

The main project's assembly's version is inspected in a post-build event and the release notes associated with that version are extracted from Trac RSS and stored as an XML file to be shipped with the application.  This is done in a post-build event.

The main assembly's project's post-build event:

```
Powershell -File "$(SolutionDir)scripts\makereleasenotes.ps1" $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)
```

This works fine in VS.

When we build deployments, however, a number of other steps happen and so there is a command-line msbuild which is run from a double-click which does the build and packages up a deployment.

When run from this process, the post-build step doesn't appear to be running.

This is the command script we use:

```
set app_main=%CD%
msbuild app.msbuild /target:Release;Cleanup
```

The app.msbuild has a target which then includes other targets:

```
<Target Name="Release" DependsOnTargets="CreateDir;BuildRelease;CopyFiles"/>
```

and:

```
<Target Name="BuildRelease" > 

    <MSBuild Projects="App.Web.Application.sln" Properties="Platform=$(Platform);Configuration=Release; 
             OutDir=$(ReleaseDir)\$(DTResult)\$(ReleaseConfiguration)\" 
             Targets="Clean;Rebuild"> 
             <Output ItemName ="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>

    </MSBuild>

    etc.
```

So you can see that our external msbuild script delegates to the solution, and there are no individual projects being compiled in our build.

Is a subordinate project's post-build script supposed to run when a solution is set as a target in an msbuild script?

If so, what is stopping mine from running?

If not, I'm assuming I will have to run it separately, and provide equivalent parameters for the project-level macros (which the powershell script is using to inspect the assembly and write out the release notes XML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by spaces in the paths of the builds and the macros (specifically $ProjectDir which ends in a ).  The build script set the path to include spaces of the form "yyyy MM dd HH-mm".  This the parameters to the Powershell were invalid when spearated by those spaces.

You cannot just add double quotes to the parameters in the post-build, because the $(ProjectDir) marco expands to DRIVE:\something\something\ and when you put "" around this, you just end up with "DRIVE:\something\something\" which actually expands the trailing \" to " instead of \ - which completely messes it up.

Ended up just removing the spaces so that the parameters were whole and did not need to figure out how to get the quotes working in the post-build script.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. :)

Comment: I had that same problem. You can add another backslash at the end of the macro, then you can wrap it in quotes. So for example `Foo "$(ProjectDir)\"` which expands to e.g. `Foo "C:\Bar Baz\Boop Bap\\"`. The double-backslash gets mangled away and you are left with a quoted string with spaces, which will be interpreted as one single argument.

Answer (score 1):

I am a relative newbie to MSBuild, but I see your question has been sitting there for 4 hours unanswered.

First, the only thing I can think of is that you are using the macro $(SolutionDir) in the post build event to pass to the powershell script. Perhaps that is getting resolved to a directory that you don't expect and thus powershell can't find it. I personally never use any macro's related to solution, but that's just me. When I need a reserved path back to an MSBuild file, I always use $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) because I think it gets resolved earlier than other macros. So in short, perhaps $(SolutionDir) is getting resolved too late?

Second, perhaps you could add other simple hello world type commands to your build event commands. Something that helps print out debug information about what your macro's are getting resolved to. Perhaps some echo commands?

Sorry if this doesn't help, but without looking at your actual build configuration, it's hard to say.

Comment: I had put in an `echo 'post-build' > $(SolutionDir)status.txt` and nothing happened but didn't try the other folder - you might be on to something there - I'll check that tomorrow morning.

Comment: This put me on the right track to troubleshooting it at least.